# Starting a thread to timeout the main thread, but allow the main thread to pause the timer

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have a C function `expensive_call` that I want to add a 'timeout' on. For this I use pthreads: I create a separate thread which calls `nanosleep` and afterwards sends a signal (`SIGUSR1`) to the main thread.

However, the main thread is allowed to mark certain pieces of the code as not counting towards the timeout. So I came up with the idea that the main thread can send a signal (`SIGUSR2`) to the timer thread to pause/resume the timer.

I use `sigsetjmp`/`siglongjmp` to return from the expensive call when the main thread receives `SIGUSR1`. The signal handler for `SIGUSR2` is empty.

There are two problems with my current implementation below:

1. Sometimes `SIGUSR2` is received but `nanosleep` is not stopped, and `expensive_call` is interrupted anyway. (For this I have tried to add `sched_yield();` right above `for (;;);` in `expensive_call`, to allow the timer thread to take over, but this does not have any effect.)
2. This solution requires both `SIGUSR1` and `SIGUSR2`, and I'd like to think I didn't have to use both for this.

Any ideas to solve these issues would be welcome!

The intended output of the program below is:

```
[main thread]  start expensive call
[timer thread] received SIGUSR2
[timer thread] pausing timer
(does not terminate)
```

But sometimes we get (this is problem 1 above):

```
[main thread]  start expensive call
[timer thread] received SIGUSR2
[timer thread] killing main thread...
[main thread]  received SIGUSR1
[main thread]  expensive_call() was interrupted
```

The program itself:

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static pthread_t main_thread,timer_thread;
static jmp_buf restore_point;

static void handle_sigusr1 (int sig)
{
    fprintf (stderr,"received SIGUSR1\n");
    siglongjmp (restore_point,sig);
}

static void handle_sigusr2 (int sig)
{
    fprintf (stderr,"received SIGUSR2\n");
}

static void *timer (void *arg)
{
    struct timespec timeout;
    sigset_t sigset;
    int _unused;

    pthread_setcanceltype (PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS,&_unused);

    /* We ignore everything except SIGUSR2, which is used in sigwait below */
    sigfillset (&sigset);
    sigdelset (&sigset,SIGUSR2);
    pthread_sigmask (SIG_SETMASK,&sigset,NULL);

    sigemptyset (&sigset);
    sigaddset (&sigset,SIGUSR2);

    timeout.tv_sec=1;
    timeout.tv_nsec=0;
    /* On interrupt, wait for SIGUSR2, then continue to sleep */
    while (nanosleep (&timeout,&timeout) == -1 && errno==EINTR){
        fprintf (stderr,"pausing timer\n");
        sigwait (&sigset,&_unused);
        fprintf (stderr,"continuing timer\n");
    }

    fprintf (stderr,"killing main thread...\n");
    pthread_kill (main_thread,SIGUSR1);

    return NULL;
}

static void expensive_call (void)
{
    fprintf (stderr,"start expensive call\n");

    pthread_kill (timer_thread,SIGUSR2);
    for (;;);
    pthread_kill (timer_thread,SIGUSR2);

    fprintf (stderr,"end expensive call\n");
}

void main (void)
{
    struct sigaction signal_handler;

    /* Install signal handlers */
    signal_handler.sa_handler=handle_sigusr1;
    sigemptyset(&signal_handler.sa_mask);
    signal_handler.sa_flags=SA_RESTART;
    if (sigaction (SIGUSR1,&signal_handler,NULL)!=0)
        perror ("sigaction");

    signal_handler.sa_handler=handle_sigusr2;
    if (sigaction (SIGUSR2,&signal_handler,NULL)!=0)
        perror ("sigaction");

    /* Setup threads */
    main_thread=pthread_self();
    pthread_create (&timer_thread,NULL,timer,NULL);

    /* Actual computation */
    if (sigsetjmp (restore_point,1)!=0){
        fprintf (stderr,"expensive_call() was interrupted\n");
    } else {
        expensive_call();
    }

    /* Cleanup */
    pthread_cancel (timer_thread);
    pthread_join (timer_thread,NULL);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps instead of using threads and signals, just have `expensive_call()` store the current wall-clock time at the beginning of its execution, and then periodically check the difference between the current wall-clock time and the stored wall-clock time, and if the difference is larger than the specified threshold, have it return.  (You can implement the "pauses" inside `expensive_call()` by adding the time spent inside the "paused sections" to the stored wall-clock time)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I don't have much control over `expensive_call()`. It is an interpreter loop, so I could put a check in the main loop but that would be slow since one iteration is very fast. Only some of the instructions implemented should be able to pause the timer.

Comment: If you're worried about the overhead of too many timer-checks, you could always do something to reduce the frequency, like e.g. `static int counter = 0; if (++counter == 100000) {counter = 0; check_timer();}`

Comment: @JeremyFriesner yes, but even the overhead of the counter would be noticeable.

Comment: I doubt it, but that would be easy enough to measure and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented a solution along the lines of what sbo [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61873677) using a mutex and a condition variable. The condition variable is used for signaling in both directions.

1. The main thread starts the timer thread and waits for the condition variable. This allows the timer thread to start up, solving my first problem.
2. The timer thread signals the condition variable and does a `pthread_cond_timedwait()` to wait until at most the timeout.
3. If the main thread finishes in time, it cancels the timer thread. Otherwise, the timer thread kills the main thread when `ETIMEDOUT` occurs.
4. To allow for sections in `expensive_call()` that are not counted towards the timeout, the main thread signals the condition variable before entering and after exiting such a section. The timer thread, upon receiving this signal, computes the remaining timeout, and proceeds with step 2 once the main thread has exited the uncounted section.

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static pthread_t main_thread,timer_thread;
static pthread_mutex_t mutex=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
static pthread_cond_t cv;

static void *timer (void *arg)
{
    struct timespec start_time,wait_time,end_time;
    int _unused,err;

    pthread_setcanceltype (PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS,&_unused);

    wait_time.tv_sec=1;
    wait_time.tv_nsec=0;

    clock_gettime (CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&start_time);
    end_time.tv_sec=start_time.tv_sec+wait_time.tv_sec;
    end_time.tv_nsec=start_time.tv_nsec+wait_time.tv_nsec;

    for (;;)
    {
        pthread_cond_signal (&cv);
        err=pthread_cond_timedwait (&cv,&mutex,&end_time);

        if (!err){
            clock_gettime (CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&end_time);
            wait_time.tv_sec=wait_time.tv_sec-(end_time.tv_sec-start_time.tv_sec);
            wait_time.tv_nsec=wait_time.tv_nsec-(end_time.tv_nsec-start_time.tv_nsec);

            pthread_cond_signal (&cv);
            pthread_cond_wait (&cv,&mutex);

            clock_gettime (CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&start_time);
            end_time.tv_sec=start_time.tv_sec+wait_time.tv_sec;
            end_time.tv_nsec=start_time.tv_nsec+wait_time.tv_nsec;
            continue;
        }

        if (err==ETIMEDOUT){
            fprintf (stderr,"killing main thread...\n");
            pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex);
            pthread_kill (main_thread,SIGUSR1);
            break;
        } else {
            perror ("pthread_mutex_timedlock");
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}

static void enter_uncounted_section (void)
{
    pthread_cond_signal (&cv);
    pthread_cond_wait (&cv,&mutex);
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex);
}

static void exit_uncounted_section (void)
{
    pthread_cond_signal (&cv);
    pthread_cond_wait (&cv,&mutex);
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex);
}

static void expensive_call (void)
{
    fprintf (stderr,"start expensive call\n");

    enter_uncounted_section();
    for (long long int i=0; i<1000000000L; i++);
    exit_uncounted_section();

    fprintf (stderr,"exited uncounted section\n");

    for (long long int i=0; i<1000000000L; i++);

    fprintf (stderr,"end expensive call\n");
}

static jmp_buf restore_point;

static void handle_sigusr1 (int sig)
{
    fprintf (stderr,"received SIGUSR1\n");
    siglongjmp (restore_point,sig);
}

void main (void)
{
    struct sigaction signal_handler;
    pthread_condattr_t attr;

    /* Install signal handlers */
    signal_handler.sa_handler=handle_sigusr1;
    sigemptyset(&signal_handler.sa_mask);
    signal_handler.sa_flags=SA_RESTART;
    if (sigaction (SIGUSR1,&signal_handler,NULL)!=0)
        perror ("sigaction");

    /* Setup threads */
    pthread_condattr_init (&attr);
    pthread_condattr_setclock (&attr,CLOCK_MONOTONIC);
    pthread_cond_init (&cv,&attr);

    main_thread=pthread_self();
    pthread_create (&timer_thread,NULL,timer,NULL);

    /* Actual computation */
    if (sigsetjmp (restore_point,1)!=0){
        fprintf (stderr,"expensive_call() was interrupted\n");
    } else {
        pthread_cond_wait (&cv,&mutex);
        pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex);
        expensive_call();
    }

    /* Cleanup */
    pthread_cancel (timer_thread);
    pthread_join (timer_thread,NULL);
    pthread_cond_destroy (&cv);
    pthread_mutex_destroy (&mutex);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me why you don't implement a concept using semaphores for example.

Semaphores are an usual and the most simple way for signaling in between threads. But it requires you to code checkpoints for the semaphore to trigger functions.

Edit:
breaking it down a semaphore could be seen as a global variable (or at least in the scope of the code for the involved threads). While the real purpose is to signal that a certain part is ready for an other thread to process it, you could steel just a fraction of it: the global variable.

From what I understand your approach is the attempt to implement a kind of software watchdog. A watchdog basically will reset if it runs out a specific time to detect if there is a undefined state of the software or a dead lock. Therefore I would go for the simple solution to set a global variable with the time you would accept (with some safety buffer), and having the timer-thread just counting down. If it reaches 0, kill the main-thread.

To Pause or simply skip over the expensive call that is out of your control but trusted, I'd set up the time to its max and terminate the thread. To resume re-create after the expensive call returned.

Comment: thanks for that idea, could you unpack it a little more? I'm not sure if it's applicable, but it might be, so any pointers to useful functions/documentation would be helpful. Please also see [my comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61872992/starting-a-thread-to-timeout-the-main-thread-but-allow-the-main-thread-to-pause?noredirect=1#comment109438476_61872992).

Comment: Thank you. I read up a bit more on pthreads mutexes and condition variables and wrote a full answer myself: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61877801